# Whats the correct way to release a @property / IBOulet for UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've read many different things about correct memory management for cocoa/objective-c

For instance ive read that any IBOutlets need to be set to 'nil' but something like an NSArray dosnt?

I would also like to know, is it important to call the super method before or after i release/nil everything

To put this memory issue to bed, can some please reply with the 100% correct way you would create a retained property and release it. If your not 100% sure please dont answer.

Here is what im currently doing but something is obviously wrong as i get the very frustrating EXEC_BAD_ACCESS!?! Almost like im releasing something twice?

header.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

    UILabel *aLabel;
    NSArray *aArray;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *aLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *aArray;
```

method.m

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize aLabel, aArray;

- (void)dealloc
{
     [aLabel release], aLabel = nil;
     [aArray release];
     [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.aLabel = nil; //Not sure about this bad boy???
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

Comment: You've got the right idea. 'aLabel = nil' in the dealloc is unnecessary, but harmless. Where is your crash happening?

Comment: Argh jeez, just found i was releasing my property in one of my methods for some crazy reason. I knew it was releasing twice!!! SO what im doing is correct then? Just ommit the aLabel = nil in the dealloc and its all happy days?

Comment: 'aLabel = nil' isn't going to crash or anything. It's just clearing out an ivar that is just about to go away with the rest of the object. So it's just not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dealloc you have released the aLabel.Means it is not in memory.Again you are write this line  ---aLabel=nil;Remove this line.So that it can't gives the Exec_badaccess.This means eventhough you don't have pointer stilll you are trying to access the pointer.